# How to overcome a Destination Folder Access Denied Error when adding a Group Policy administrative template files for PCoIP?

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I'm following the [Install the Group Policy administrative template for PCoIP (64-Bit) guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/group_policy.html#gp_install_template) and I'm getting an error on step 6: "If it doesn't already exist, create a folder named PolicyDefinitions." When I attempt to create the folder I get a "Destination Folder Access Denied Error." I've attempted changing the ownership of the folder but that access is denied as well. Any ideas how I can create this folder?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the user from which I was trying to create the folder is not part of the "Group Policies Creators Owners" group.

The simplest way to fix this is to login to the domain joined machine(workspace/EC2) with directory administrator(Administrator) credentials of your simpleAD domain. Once you have a logged into the machine you can create the folder.

My EC2 instance was not domain joined so I had to manually domain join a Windows instance as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_windows_instance.html).

Once you are logged as a directory administrator you should be able to create the folders in the sysvol, you can follow the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/group_policy.html).

Alternatively you can RDP to the workspaces with domain administrator credentials by following the steps [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/connect-workspace-rdp).

Comment: I'm logged in as CORP/Administrator for a Simple AD domain (and my regular user is also part of the Group Policies) and neither of these accounts have access to create this directory. Super annoying.

Comment: OK. I got mine to work. I right clicked on the "Policies" folder and went to Properties. Then on the Security tab I granted "Full Control" to the "Group Policies Creators Owners". It gave me an error afterwards but then I could create the directory.